# How to generate 2 new input fields when click add new button and insert data into database using php-pdo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I have a html form below.when user click add new button then 2 new input fields (warishan names and relation) will generate.user can add many fields. how can i do this and also store the data into two table, where name and contact goes to userinfo table
and userid(last_inserted),warishan names and relations goes to relation table.Anybody help please ?

```
<form id='test' action=""method="post">
Name : <input type="text" id="applicantName" name="applicantName" value="" placeholder="Your Name">
Contact : <input type="text" id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" value="" placeholder="Contact Number">

<label class="label"> <strong> Warishan Names <strong> </label>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> # </th>
<th>Warishan Names</th>
<th>Relations</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="wname" id="wname" value="" placeholder=" "></td>
<td><input type="text" name="wr" id="wr" value="" placeholder=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table> 

<button> add new Warishan </button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as it is. I've checked this code. Working fine.

```
<form id='test' action="SomePage.php" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" id="applicantName" name="applicantName" value="" placeholder="Your Name">
    Contact : <input type="text" id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" value="" placeholder="Contact Number">

    <label class="label"> <strong> Warishan Names <strong> </label>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="form_table" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>Warishan Names</th>
                <th>Relations</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class='case'>
                <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='wname[]'/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type='text' name='wr[]'/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ add new Warishan</button> <br>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addmore").on('click', function () {
            var count = $('table tr').length;
            var data = "<tr class='case'><td><span id='snum" + count + "'>" + count + ".</span></td>";
            data += "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='wname[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='wr[]'/></td></tr>";
            $('#form_table').append(data);
            count++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Create **SomePage.php**, and give it to `action` attribute of `<form></form>` too.

Like : `<form id='test' action="SomePage.php" method="post">`

**SomePage.php**

```
<?
$wname=$_POST['wname'];
$wr=$_POST['wr'];

$totalName=sizeof($wname);

for($i=0;$i<$totalName;$i++)
{
    $name = $wname[$i];
    $relation = $wr[$i];
    echo $name." ".$relation."<br>";

    //Use $name and $relation in your query. 
}
?>
```

Comment: Small tip on this great answer, make sure to also include security checks/cleanup on the $_POSTs if you're writing to database

Comment: wow ...Thank you @Nana Partykar . you made my day sir. this is the code what i wanted. it's solved my problem.

Comment: @Nana Partykar ...can u help me lil bit??? how can i remove extra generated field with a remove icon (if not need one by one)??? demo[link](http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-text-fields-jquery/)

Comment: Yeah. It is possible. But, you have to wait for 15-20 min. I busy working in office. Don't mind. I will be back after 20 min. @RiyadhAhmed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add some `input`fields when you're clicking your button, right?
To do so, use javascript (you can try jQuery for this purpose).
PHP is a server-side scripting language, you shouldn't use it
for front-end stuff like you want.

Comment: yes. i know that it's need to use jquery to generate input fields. but how can i generate 2 fields? also when submit how can i get two fields values using php?

Comment: For getting two field value you have two options: 1. Try to get them out of $_GET variable, 2. Try to get them from your database. In a case if you're having trouble with accomplishing your task just get in touch with me: psanatov(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: i found some information here [link](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/) but here is one filed generated but i need two. also how can  i get the posted data using foreach loop.thanks.

Comment: Something like this: foreach($_POST as $k => $v) { return "key - ".$k.", value - ".$v; }